# Save changes made by user in editText

Tags: java, android

I have two `Activities` in my application. The first `Activity` shows a list of all videos. When I click on any video, another `Activity` is opened which calls `VideoEditorActivity`.

All I want is, when a user makes changes in the Video title field, the user should be able to save the changes that he made through a `FloatingActionButton`. I don't want to use  `sharedPreference`, or database or file I/O. I want these changes only locally through the server.

This is my POJO:

```
public class VideoDetail implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5294188737237640015L;

    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public VideoDetail (JSONObject jsonObject){
        try {
            title = jsonObject.getString("title");
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is `VideoEditorActivity`

```
public class VideoEditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etTitle;
    FloatingActionButton btnSave;

    btnSave = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    final VideoDetail videoDetail = (VideoDetail) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");
    etTitle.setText(videoDetail.getTitle());

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // something need to do here
            // code here

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Formatted the code. But how the question is stated, it makes no sense.

Comment: I edited the question to fix the grammar and punctuation. I also formatted the code words in the text so that the question is clearer for the reader and changed the acronym "FAB" to its long meaning. I hope the question is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like the apache http client to post to your server.

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... data) {
                String url = data[0];
                String userID = data[1];
                String title = data[2];

                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", userID));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));

                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                new DefaultHttpClient().execute(post);
            }
        }.execute(<your server url>, <user ID>, etTitle.getText());
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll need back-end implementation to support this.